# Is there a proof for the maximum principle without the Cauchy integral theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

All the theorems about holomorphic functions seem to rely on the Cauchy integral theorem: Liouvilles theorem about bounded whole functions, the maximum principle, the open mapping theorem for holomorphic functions, Riemanns theorem about removabe singularities, etc. I see that the Cauchy integral theorem is powerful but are there other ways to prove one of these theorems that *do not* directly or implicitely use the Cauchy integral theorem?

Comment: Holomorphic functions are harmonic, and the maximum principle for real-valued harmonic functions implies the maximum modulus principle for holomorphic functions. But the usual way via the Cauchy theorems is easier, IMO.

Comment: @DanielFischer That's an answer :-)

Comment: @DanielFischer  I think to get that they are harmonic, we need at least that they are second differentiable, whose proof passes through the cauchy integral theorem.

Comment: @StevenGubkin Yes! If you already knew that holomorphic $\Leftrightarrow$ analytic, the rest would be no problem!

Comment: @StevenGubkin Depends on what you want to throw at it. From the Cauchy-Riemann equations it follows that they are harmonic in the sense of distributions. And we have regularity theorems, harmonic distributions are in fact $C^\infty$. _Checks_: Yes, I did say the usual way was easier ;)

Comment: I heard that there was some sort of a dispute between Liouville and Cauchy. It sounded like Liouville proved his theorem without Cauchys integral theorem. How would you do that?

Comment: Also, I read [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/116896/liouvilles-theorem-with-your-bare-hands) that you can deduce Liouvilles theorem from Riemanns theorem for removable singularities. But I don't know how to prove _that_ without Cauchy!

Comment: I don't know how Liouville proved it, but the theorem also holds for harmonic functions, a bounded entire (defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$) harmonic function is constant (follows from the Poisson integral). Also you have a removable singularity theorem for harmonic functions (in real dimensions two or larger), so you can do a lot with the theory of harmonic functions. But, once again, the route with the Cauchy theorems is easier and more instructive.

Comment: The Poisson integral representation for a harmonic function on a disk is all you need to know. Historically, this representation came well before the Cauchy integral representation (1823). I think that Cauchy started with this representation in the process of coming to his representation, but I may be wrong about that.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively there's a topological approach, all the results rely in a *topological index* which is used to obtain the *winding number* of a curve around a point.

The reference is *Topological Analysis* by Gordon Thomas Whyburn.